# How to set the Application Name for a Sequelize application

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, tedious

I've got a nodejs application that uses Sequelize as it's ORM. I've successfully got Sequelize connected to the database, but I haven't found anything in the documentation that explains how to set the application name. To clarify I'm looking to set a unique Application Name attribute for my app's connection string. That way when a DBA is looking at traffic they can pick out my application's queries from the rest.

Is this something that Sequelize can even do? Or does this need to be done at the tedious level? Failing that, is there a way in nodejs to specify connection string attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tedious allows setting the app name with the `appName` config param. You should be able to set this via the `dialectOptions` object when creating your Sequelize connection:

```
var conn = new Sequelize('my_db', 'my_user', 'my_pass', {
  host: 'my_server',
  dialect: 'mssql',

  dialectOptions: {
    appName: 'my_app_name'
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In a standalone nodejs/sequelize app this works 100%. I ran into issues trying to use this in a sails application with the sails-hook-sequelize module. If I find a solution to that issue I will include it on this page.

Comment: Post a new question and answer it yourself if you do :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40444535/how-to-set-appname-connection-string-using-sails-hook-sequelize-application Here is the new question

Comment: Looks like your answer worked for sails-hook-sequelize as well. Seems like my method of capturing the application name had been wrong. Using MS SQL Profiler I was able to see the updated Application name. Seeing as how this answer covers both questions, I have deleted the question I asked above (40444535)

Comment: I still get Tedious as application_name, could you please take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56903706/setting-appname-dialectoptions-of-sequelize-connection-does-not-work

Comment: apologies, it’s been years since I’ve used Sequelize. Perhaps @OrwellHindenberg can help you.

Comment: In newer versions you must add options inside dialectOptions like:
```
var conn = new Sequelize('my_db', 'my_user', 'my_pass', {
  host: 'my_server',
  dialect: 'mssql',

  dialectOptions: {
    options: {
        appName: 'my_app_name'
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: application_name for postgres

Answer (score 2):

For those finding this when they're looking for how to set the name for Postgres, you use `application_name` in the `dialectOptions`, eg

```
{
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    host: DB_HOST,
    dialect: 'postgresql',
    dialectOptions: {
        application_name: 'My Node App',
    },
},
```