# How to set application name in sequelize connection object?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, tedious

**Summary:**

I want to change the `application name` of the `connection string` when initialize a new sequalize object. based on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404738/how-to-set-the-application-name-for-a-sequelize-application), I set the appName of dialectOptions as follows:

```
    let conn = new Sequelize(this.models.sequelize.config.database, this.models.sequelize.config.username,
                this.models.sequelize.config.password, {
                host: this.models.sequelize.config.host,
                dialect: this.models.sequelize.getDialect(),
                dialectOptions: {
                    appName: "userid=-2@gid=" + gid
                }
            });
```

**Question:**

When I execute a transaction like the following code, the `application name` does not pass to the SQL server. When I monitor the execution of SQL queries, the following picture shows that `Tedious` was sent to the application name.

transaction code:

```
    await conn.transaction(async t => {
                for(let i in this.collect){
                    let queryBuilder = this.collect[i];
                    let options = {replacements: queryBuilder.replacement, transaction: t};
                    if(queryBuilder.type === 'insert'){
                        options.type = conn.QueryTypes.INSERT;
                    }
                    let row = await conn.query(queryBuilder.query + ';select @@IDENTITY as id', options);
                    progressBar.update(parseInt(i) + 1);
                }
```

and the SQL Profiler picture is:

[image]

How can I set the `Application Name` properly?

Comment: It's been awhile since I used Sequelize, but can you use a hard coded value for your dialect such as 'mssql' instead of what you have `dialect: this.models.sequelize.getDialect()` So you would have `dialect: 'mssql'` or use postgres, mysql or whatever your dialect is?

Comment: It is still the same. the `application name` is still Tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must set appName in options object so correct syntax is

```
let conn = new Sequelize(this.models.sequelize.config.database, this.models.sequelize.config.username,
            this.models.sequelize.config.password, {
            host: this.models.sequelize.config.host,
            dialect: this.models.sequelize.getDialect(),
            dialectOptions: {
               options: {
                  appName: "userid=-2@gid=" + gid
               }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

On PostgreSQL, you need to set the property `application_name` in the `dialectOptions` object like that:

```
let conn = new Sequelize(this.models.sequelize.config.database, this.models.sequelize.config.username,
            this.models.sequelize.config.password, {
            host: this.models.sequelize.config.host,
            dialect: "postgres",
            dialectOptions: {
               application_name: "yourApp"
            }
        });
```